# Mods: converted answer to comment?

Tags: discussion, moderation

My answer [in this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/what-is-wrong-with-wealth-inequality) was deleted and put as a comment instead. I believe that it should be an answer instead. As a simple metric, see that it was even too long for a simple comment - the remainder of my answer which didn't fit in, was simple removed.

The question remains whether moderators should follow this practice in general, instead of waiting for the community to decide (via NaN flags).

Comment: Still looking into this, but it was probably flagged for moderator attention if we did something. On mobile now so i can't see the history, but I'll look in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I converted this, but it was not a unilateral action: it was flagged by the community as not an answer. My judgement was that this flag was justified given that the main thrust of what you say is that the question is not clear enough to be answered in its current form.

I apologize for truncating what you wrote (I did not realize that I had done this), but I do not think that length is the best metric for whether something constitutes an answer or not. For the sake of future visitors to the site, answers should be reserved for clear and concise answers; comments, voting, and flagging are the appropriate means by which the need for improvement in a question can be expressed.

Comment: I actually disagree. The "bad thing" is a recurring issue. People keep asking whether inequality is "bad", and hence I think both the question "is inequality bad" and the corresponding answer "bad has no sufficient meaning" deserve their space on this site. While having emphasized lack of clearness or potential improvements in comments many times before on this site, here I purposefully wrote this as an answer and not a comment.

Comment: @FooBar if a question is unclear, the thing to do is to vote to close it as unclear. You can, if you wish, add a comment explaining what is unclear, and how it can be made clear.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers the question is not unclear. It is perfectly clear. The point "The way you think is wrong" is not a comment, it is an answer - imo.